# setting a cookie that expire on second load of a page

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have to launch a modal window only on some pages and only when is the first time that, for the specified user, that particular page is loaded.

How can i make this? I want to use javascript.

I think i have to set a cookie and set a variable that is the page loading but how?

Comment: This [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#A_little_framework.3A_a_complete_cookies_reader.2Fwriter_with_full_unicode_support) provide a tiny framework that makes it a lot easier to work with cookies in JavaScript. The URL of the current page is available in `window.location.href`. Putting them together might work as a good exercise.

Comment: sorry but can't i do it in a few rows? i have window.location.href to be an int or something like that

Answer (score -1):

You have to set cooike for each of that page...

```
jQuery.cookie('test', true, {expires: 30})
```

So you will have a cookie for current opened page and for 30 days.
Default value of the path attribute of the cookie is the page that created the cookie.

Comment: ok but how to transform the window.location.href in a variable in which i can say "if this action is performed window... that is 0 ++window, when window = 1 destroy session)

Comment: if ( !jQuery.cookie('test') ) { // if there is no cookie for this page let's do smhtg.
 // do smthg; show modal window 4example;
 jQuery.cookie('test', true, {expires: 30}) //and then set the cookie for not showing previous operation at the future;
}